# To sync /var or not?

Tags: mount, logs, failure-resistance

It seems in a hard crash, in particular failure of a UPS to keep a system running, that some of the contents of logs get lost due to file system caching.  As an experiment, I tried mounting the /var partition with the sync option.  There was substantially more disk noise on a boot up, but the show stopper was trying to run apt.  The disk pounded away while apt sat there unresponsive.

Is it a mistake to mount /var sync, or is one of the options such as relatime, strictatime or noatime required for success?  If so, is it safe to use one of these options on /var?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enabling `sync` on the filesystem level is usually not a good solution (usually, not always). When `sync` is enabled, it not only forces a buffer flush on every single write, it also negates the filesystem's ability to re-order writes to optimize IO (by writing larger chunks). This also results in higher fragmentation.

The better solution is to get whatever application youre using to use `fsync` (or `fdatasync`) instead. When an application writes out data, it can make a call to `fsync` which will force that data out to disk. This way it's only certain data that is being synced all the time, and not the whole filesystem. It also is a little more intelligent as the `fsync` can be called once the application has written all its data, and not on every little bit.

If youre using syslog-ng, it has the ability to enable `fsync` on per file destination ([documentation](http://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-ose-3.3-guides/syslog-ng-ose-v3.3-guide-admin-en.html/index.html-single.html#id621637)).  rsyslog might also have this feature, but I do not know.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on ``syslog-ng''.

Comment: From what I'd seen in rsyslog the synced writes are the default. You have to prepend the filename with a hyphen (eg, -/var/log/messages) to disable sync.